# Python write newline to file gives ਍一愀洀攀ऀ䄀爀琀椀猀琀ഀ rather than newline

Tags: python, line, newline, line-breaks

Here is overall code, for taking a tab delimetted text file, and creating a new file that only takes the first two values.

```
    fin = open("in.txt", 'r')
    fout = open("out.txt", 'w')

    for line in fin:

        mrList = line.split('\t')
        fout.write(mrList[0] + "\t" + mrList[1])
        fout.write('\n')

    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

When this goes in:

```
Hello world<tab>how are you?<tab>Groovy
Like pie?<tab>I love it<tab>omnomnom
Go pikachu!<tab>Use pound!<tab>She like
```

This comes out:

```
Hello world<tab>how are you?਍䰀椀欀攀 瀀椀攀㼀ऀ䤀 氀漀瘀攀 椀琀ഀ
Go pikachu!<tab>Use pound!਍
```

I suspect that '\n' is not quite a newline, and googling it insists "its definitely \n 0_0"

UPDATE:

Since answer below, (thanks!) discovered that on a Linux command line:

```
file peskyInputFile.txt
```

Tells you the encoding, and that

```
iconv -c -f utf-16 -t utf-8 peskyInputFile.txt -o outputFile.txt
```

will convert a UTF-16 file to UTF-8, which circumvents hassle if you don't need to deal with UTF16

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python thinks a 3000-line text file is one line long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184543/python-thinks-a-3000-line-text-file-is-one-line-long)

Comment: Not a "possible duplicate" from the a novice OP's point of view. The suggested duplicate has no accepted answer, the seemingly most correct answer is buried down near the end, and the problem was trying to read CR (classic Mac) line terminators in a UTF-16BE text file on linux. The current problem is trying to treat a UTF-16 text file with LF terminators as though it were ASCII.

Comment: @JohnMachin Fair point. I am simply asserting that the solution is the same — namely, decode from bytes before processing characters, regardless of the specific symptom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is encoded in UTF-16, and you are attempting to process it like ASCII. When you strip the newline, you only consume one byte, so the UTF-16 is off by one until the next newline. See “[Python thinks a 3000-line text file is one line long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184543/python-thinks-a-3000-line-text-file-is-one-line-long)” for a solution and explanation.

This is what you’re doing:

```
>>> b = u'Like pie?\tI love it\tomnomnom'.encode('utf-16le')
>>> s = ('\n' + b + '\0').decode('utf-16le')
>>> print s
䰊椀欀攀 瀀椀攀㼀ऀ䤀 氀漀瘀攀 椀琀ऀ漀洀渀漀洀渀漀洀
```